# Read XML feed in iOS app using Swift

Tags: ios, xml, swift, rss, feed

I'm trying to parse XML data from the Internet. When I'm using a first source I get all the data I want. But when I'm trying to change another source I only get the last two elements from the source.

In other words, supposing I want to get a list composed by 10 elements, I only get the 9 and 10 elements.

In fact I need to get title and description, but even in the 9 and 10 I only get a part of the description.

Here is the code I used.

The code is in Swift for iOS 9.

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController ,NSXMLParserDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var tbData: UITableView?

    var parser = NSXMLParser()
    var posts = NSMutableArray()
    var elements = NSMutableDictionary()
    var element = NSString()
    var title1 = NSMutableString()
    var descript = NSMutableString()

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.beginParsing()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func beginParsing()
    {
        posts = []
        parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL:(NSURL(string:"http://193.95.2.149/veterinary/dog"))!)!
        parser.delegate = self
        parser.parse()

        tbData!.reloadData()
    }

    //XMLParser Methods

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String])
    {
        element = elementName
        if (elementName as NSString).isEqualToString("item")
        {
            elements = NSMutableDictionary()
            elements = [:]
            title1 = NSMutableString()
            title1 = ""
            descript = NSMutableString()
            descript = ""
        }
    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?)
    {
        if (elementName as NSString).isEqualToString("item") {
            if !title1.isEqual(nil) {
                elements.setObject(title1, forKey: "title")
            }
            if !descript.isEqual(nil) {
                elements.setObject(descript, forKey: "pubDate")
          }

            posts.addObject(elements)
        }
    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String)
    {
        if element.isEqualToString("title") {
            title1.appendString(string)
        } else if element.isEqualToString("pubDate") {
            descript.appendString(string)
       }
    }

    //Tableview Methods

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return posts.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        var cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")!

        if(cell.isEqual(NSNull)) {
            cell = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("Cell", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UITableViewCell;
        }

        cell.textLabel?.text = posts.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("title") as! NSString as String
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = posts.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("pubDate") as! NSString as String

        return cell as UITableViewCell
    }
}
```

Comment: try this library, it will make things much easier: https://github.com/cezheng/Fuzi